# Cordova error while building android using CLI

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-cli

I am struggling through the cordova more than a week as i new to it.

I have added android platform and i am facing the following issue while building that android environment:

[image]

P.S.

Cordova - 6.0.0

Android SDKs - API 19 to API 23
Windows 8

Please help me as soon as possible.

Comment: had you did `cordova platform add android` previously?

Comment: @Del yup i have already added it.